# batch FFMPEG-Normalize AND convert via Python?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, python, mp3

I am currently working on a script to help me batch convert and
normalize audio files (wma to mp3)
In the search of useful tools I was lucky to stumble on FFMPEG-Normalize!

My script is running from Python and I am calling FFMPEG via subprocess.
I could not get the FFMPEG-Normalize to output Mp3 files - thus I am
doing another FFMPEG call  to convert the resulted wav files. 
Do you know how to make FFMPEG normalize also convert to mp3 ?
The second issue is that only part of the files in my folder are being
processed, I cant understand why. Out of 8 files I have in the path,
sometimes all of them are processed and sometimes only 3, or 5... very
weird!
Here is my code :

```
for file in sorted(os.listdir(pathdes)):
    os.chdir(pathdes)
    subprocess.call(['ffmpeg-normalize','-m','-l','-0.1',file])
    file = 'normalized-' + file
    file = file[:-3] + "wav"
    file2 = file[:-3] + "mp3"
    os.chdir(pathdes)
    subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i', file,'-b:a','320k', file2])
```

I understand FFMPEG normalize was written in Python, maybe there is
another way to call it other than subprocess ?
Am I missing something ? (i know i am !)

Thank you so much !

Comment: I should add that the `ffmpeg-normalize` program isn't pythonic in the sense of not being written in such a way that you could just `import` it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ffmpeg-normalize` tool allows you to set an audio encoder as well, using the `-a`, `--acodec <acodec>` option.

For example, to EBU R128-normalize a bunch of WAV files and encode them to MP3 with `libmp3lame`:

```
ffmpeg-normalize --ebu --acodec libmp3lame --extra-options "-b:a 192k" *.wav
```

Note that for MP3 specifically, you could use [MP3Gain](http://mp3gain.sourceforge.net/) to change the volume without having to re-encode the files.

Comment: command = ['ffmpeg-normalize','--debug','--acodec','libmp3lame','--extra-options','-b:a 320k','--format','mp3','-m','-l','-0.1',file]

Comment: thank you ! the above is the full command to convert to mp3. (--format as well) the reason for getting no normalized- file was the file in that case contained clips close to 0db..